# Why are "mixture" and "predict" giving different results in the DirichletMultinomial R package

Tags: r, mixture-model, dirichlet

I have been using the DirichletMultinomial R package to build some clustering of a dataset. Now, using the model I built, I would like to predict these groups on another dataset. Before doing that, I just used predict on my original dataset and I was surprised by the result.

If I do it on the Twins dataset included in the DirichletMultinomial package, I have the following results, which seem almost identical.

```
> fl <- system.file(package="DirichletMultinomial", "extdata","Twins.csv")
> count <- t(as.matrix(read.csv(fl, row.names=1)))
> fit <- mclapply(1:7, dmn, count=count, verbose=TRUE)
> best <- fit[[4]]
> head(mixture(best))
                [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]
TS1.2   9.999914e-01 8.533980e-06 3.306707e-08 2.117430e-11
TS10.2  3.775494e-08 9.996731e-01 2.847409e-10 3.268341e-04
TS100.2 7.215444e-09 7.954710e-13 1.174677e-01 8.825323e-01
TS100   5.973009e-01 7.881327e-02 3.238844e-01 1.413423e-06
TS101.2 1.110644e-13 2.606683e-19 1.472201e-06 9.999985e-01
TS103.2 3.736814e-04 9.996260e-01 4.361933e-10 3.245371e-07

> head(predict(best,count))
                [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]
TS1.2   9.999914e-01 8.533549e-06 3.306516e-08 2.116933e-11
TS10.2  3.774837e-08 9.996732e-01 2.847388e-10 3.268028e-04
TS100.2 7.214920e-09 7.953494e-13 1.174489e-01 8.825511e-01
TS100   5.972792e-01 7.881798e-02 3.239015e-01 1.413737e-06
TS101.2 1.110848e-13 2.606804e-19 1.472259e-06 9.999985e-01
TS103.2 3.736395e-04 9.996260e-01 4.361901e-10 3.244978e-07
```

But if I do it on my dataset, I have some discrepancies (especially for the 2 last rows), and I do not understand where it comes from. Maybe I misunderstood the way the method is working, but I would have expected to find approximately the same results with mixture and predict. How am I mistaken here?

```
> fit <- mclapply(1:7, dmn, count=data_mat, verbose=TRUE)
> best <- fit[[5]]
> head(mixture(best))
                         [,1]         [,2]         [,3]        [,4]         [,5]
S1 1.478612e-05 9.982146e-01 3.268764e-04 0.001440704 3.017367e-06
S2 1.434083e-04 1.830344e-05 1.108533e-05 0.999827203 8.179015e-11
S3 4.216772e-13 7.048083e-09 1.467059e-01 0.853294032 6.232012e-08
S4 1.099027e-07 8.253738e-01 1.486238e-01 0.025929117 7.317699e-05
S5 3.990831e-09 4.338591e-02 5.659807e-01 0.347391684 4.324167e-02
S6 6.712974e-01 1.970030e-04 2.243382e-08 0.328505564 6.026012e-11

> head(predict(best,data_mat))
                         [,1]         [,2]         [,3]       [,4]         [,5]
S1 1.694860e-05 9.982972e-01 2.966473e-04 0.00138649 2.690955e-06
S2 1.551721e-04 1.844655e-05 1.091220e-05 0.99981547 7.825475e-11
S3 4.472069e-13 6.991368e-09 1.426672e-01 0.85733272 6.133705e-08
S4 1.439618e-07 8.320968e-01 1.405944e-01 0.02723980 6.891784e-05
S5 1.478314e-08 2.397801e-02 1.150241e-01 0.84848208 1.251575e-02
S6 8.047456e-01 2.614642e-04 7.240597e-09 0.19499295 1.107943e-10
```

Comment: When you do mixture, you are accessing the fitted probabilities, coming from an EM. You are not actually predicting again. Whereas when you use the predict function, you actually try to see the probability of the observation belong to the different groups.

Comment: In most cases it should be the same, but this is my educated guess, when you have observations near the boundary this probability will differ

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you for your answer. You are probably right about this boundary thing. I checked on my overall dataset, and even if some probabilities change, only a few samples change groups.